# Mail merge issue on google script - in-line image & placeholder

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, mailmerge

I have a simple mail merge script on google sheets that sends emails correctly. My mail merge code does handle in-line images, but

1) it doesn't work correctly and shows "in-line image 1" instead of the actual in-line image. The in-line image becomes an attachment instead in my code.

2) Also, if i put placeholders <> <> together (Even with space or comma in between) it shows sending error with message: " Cannot call method "replace" of undefined. " Probably because the replacing of names are wrong if placeholders are on the same line.

Refer to the following images for the error code when 2 placeholders are on the same line:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kC16o.jpg)

and Actual email message sent where "inline image 1" is supposed to be where the image is:

[message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2cz5.jpg)

This is the code i have for mail merge on google sheets which replaces anything inside << >> and which matches the column header in the google sheet with the corresponding values. Can someone advise on the in-line image and placeholder problem? Much appreciated, thanks!

```js
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Get inline images and make sure they stay as inline images
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      var emailTemplate = selectedTemplate.getBody();
      var rawContent = selectedTemplate.getRawContent();
      var attachments = selectedTemplate.getAttachments();
      var cc = selectedTemplate.getCc();
      var bcc = selectedTemplate.getBcc();

      var regMessageId = new RegExp(selectedTemplate.getId(), "g");
      if (emailTemplate.match(regMessageId) != null) {
        var inlineImages = {};
        var nbrOfImg = emailTemplate.match(regMessageId).length;
        var imgVars = emailTemplate.match(/<img[^>]+>/g);
        var imgToReplace = [];
        if(imgVars != null){
          for (var i = 0; i < imgVars.length; i++) {
            if (imgVars[i].search(regMessageId) != -1) {
              var id = imgVars[i].match(/realattid=([^&]+)&/);
              if (id != null) {
                var temp = rawContent.split(id[1])[1];
                temp = temp.substr(temp.lastIndexOf('Content-Type'));
                var imgTitle = temp.match(/name="([^"]+)"/);
                if (imgTitle != null) imgToReplace.push([imgTitle[1], imgVars[i], id[1]]);
              }
            }
          }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < imgToReplace.length; i++) {
          for (var j = 0; j < attachments.length; j++) {
            if(attachments[j].getName() == imgToReplace[i][0]) {
              inlineImages[imgToReplace[i][2]] = attachments[j].copyBlob();
              attachments.splice(j, 1);
              var newImg = imgToReplace[i][1].replace(/src="[^\"]+\"/, "src=\"cid:" + imgToReplace[i][2] + "\"");
              emailTemplate = emailTemplate.replace(imgToReplace[i][1], newImg);
            }
          }
        }
      }
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        var mergeData = {
            template: emailTemplate,
            subject: selectedTemplate.getSubject(),
            plainText : selectedTemplate.getPlainBody(),
            attachments: attachments,
            inlineImages: inlineImages,
            name: name,
            from: from,
            cc: cc,
            bcc: bcc
        }

        var objects = getRowsData(dataSheet, dataRange);
        Logger.log(objects);
        for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
            var rowData = objects[i];
            if (rowData.mergeStatus != "Done" && rowData.mergeStatus != "0") {
                try {
                    processRow(rowData, kind, mergeData);
                    dataSheet.getRange(i + 2, headers.indexOf('Merge status') + 1).setValue("Done").clearFormat().setComment(new Date());
                }
                catch (e) {
                    dataSheet.getRange(i + 2, headers.indexOf('Merge status') + 1).setValue("Error").setBackground('red').setComment(e.message);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function processRow(rowData, kind, mergeData) {
        var emailText = fillInTemplateFromObject(mergeData.template, rowData);
        var emailSubject = fillInTemplateFromObject(mergeData.subject, rowData);
        var plainTextBody = fillInTemplateFromObject(mergeData.plainText, rowData);
        mergeData['htmlBody'] = emailText;
        if(rowData.cc != undefined) mergeData.cc = rowData.cc;
        if(rowData.bcc != undefined) mergeData.bcc = rowData.bcc;
        //GmailApp.sendEmail(rowData.email, emailSubject, emailText); //sends in html code
        //GmailApp.sendEmail(rowData.email, emailSubject, plainTextBody, emailText); //sends in plainText
        GmailApp.sendEmail(rowData.email, emailSubject, plainTextBody, mergeData); //sends but in-line images appear as attachments with a line inline images 1 on where the img should have been at
        //GmailApp.sendEmail(rowData.email, emailSubject, mergeData); //sends only "[object Object]"
    }

    // Replaces markers in a template string with values define in a JavaScript data object.
    // Arguments:
    //   - template: string containing markers, for instance <<Column name>>
    //   - data: JavaScript object with values to that will replace markers. For instance
    //           data.columnName will replace marker <<Column name>>
    // Returns a string without markers. If no data is found to replace a marker, it is
    // simply removed.
    function fillInTemplateFromObject(template, data) {
        template = template.replace(/&lt;&lt;/g, '<<');
        template = template.replace(/&gt;&gt;/g, '>>');
        var email = template;
        template = template.replace(/">/g, "~");
        // Search for all the variables to be replaced, for instance <<Column name>>
        var templateVars = template.match(/<<[^\>]+>>/g);
        if (templateVars != null) {
            if (template.match(/\<\<[^\%]+\>>/g) != null) {
                templateVars = templateVars.concat(template.match(/\<\<[^\%]+\>>/g));
            }
        }
        else {
            var templateVars = template.match(/\<\<[^\%]+\>>/g);
        }
        if (templateVars != null) {
            // Replace variables from the template with the actual values from the data object.
            // If no value is available, replace with the empty string.
            for (var i = 0; i < templateVars.length; ++i) {
                // normalizeHeader ignores <<>> so we can call it directly here.
                var variableData = data[normalizeHeader(templateVars[i].replace(/<[^\~]+~/, ''))];
                variableData = variableData.replace(/\r?\n/g, "<br />")
                templateVars[i] = templateVars[i].replace(/~/g, '">');
                // Check that we have a header for this merge field
                if (variableData == undefined) {
                    throw new UserException("Undefined merge field " + templateVars[i]);
                }
                email = email.replace(templateVars[i], variableData || "");
            }
        }
        return email;
    }

    // Exception
    function UserException(message) {
        this.message = message;
        this.name = "UserException";
    }
```

Comment: The reality is that most of us don't want to look through all of your code, so if you could direct us to the problem area that would be helpful.

Comment: @Cooper Thanks for the suggestion! I have edited the code to where i think the problem area is (but the bulk of that code is actually taken from a google developers example code, although edited a little)